# Cannot right-click to select sometimes

Tags: selection-tools

I am using Windows 7 Blender 2.77.

I am in edit mode, solid mode, selecting faces, I still cannot right-click to select faces on my mesh.  When I change to wireframe and right-click, I am able to choose a face and make it snowy-white dots.  When I choose shift+choose a second face, the first face becomes orange and the second face becomes snowy-white dots.  When I change back to solid, the faces remain the same color as in wireframe.

Selected faces are supposed to be orange.  Why are they snowy-white in Wireframe mode and impossible to choose in Solid mode?

I tried "Load Factory Settings," and my graphics card is Intel HD so I don't have full screen anti-aliasing, whatever that is. (referencing 2 stackexchange answers I have looked up)

**Photo 1: Right Clicked the Face in Solid**
[image: right click, nothing happens]

**Photo 2: Right Clicked the Face in Wireframe**
[image: right click in wireframe, snowy-white]

**Photo 3: Shift + Right Clicked another face in Wireframe**
[image: second face selected, is snowy-white and first is orange]

**Photo 4: Changed back to Solid mode**
[image: back to solid, selections stay the same]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your model here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? It would help to spot what's wrong.

Comment: I don't think that would help, it is actually happening on all of my files.  I will try though

Comment: It looks normal to me in that the last pic still shows the highlited face but in solid mode it's mostly hidden behind the handle.  The white speckly appearance indicates the last face selected on my machine.  In pic 3's case, the surface behind the handle would be the last face selected.  As for being unable to select surfaces, I've noticed this problem and have had to flip that face over. Goto wireframe if necessary to select the face in question, open the Tools panel at left with "T", then open Shading tab, click on "Flip".

Comment: Comment cont...  You can also select problematic faces by getting to it's other side.  Often this means moving to the inside of the model itself.

Comment: OK Thank you!  I just thought I was missing something, it does work for me to go select things in wireframe.

Comment: @Hanry Hu: the downloaded file is slightly different from above, in that the cup and the holder seem to have been merged (and then subsurfed). Btw, I can select (right click) faces normally there even in solid mode. I tried to reproduce above setup, but again, face selection works in that area, even in solid mode...

Comment: Yeah, I edited it using the wireframe, but it didn't really matter because I still can't seem to select faces in solid mode.